# Performing segue after filtering in uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, filter, segue

Im currently creating an app that has a list of locations on a uitableview. There is also a filtering function so that the locations can be filtered based on categories. When not filtering, the uitableviewcell performs the segue when clicked and the correct data gets loaded in the destination viewcontroller. However when I filter tableview, the cells get populated with the right data, but when I click the cell, the destination viewcontroller always loads the data from the first cell in the UNFILTERED tableview.

The code that I am using:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shoutoutCell", for: indexPath) as! shoutoutTableViewCell

    var shout = shoutout[indexPath.row]

    if isFiltering == true {
        shout = filteredShoutout[indexPath.row]
      } else {
        shout = shoutout[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.shoutout = shout
     cell.showsReorderControl = true
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {
     var object = shoutout[indexPath.row]

    if isFiltering == true {
        object = filteredShoutout[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        object = shoutout[indexPath.row]
    }
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "shoutoutDetailSegue", sender: object)


}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "shoutoutDetailSegue" {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? shoutoutDetailViewController {
      //  destination.shoutoutSelected = sender as! object
        destination.shoutoutSelected = shoutout[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are using `shoutout` Array in `prepare(for segue` even when filtering.

```
destination.shoutoutSelected = shoutout[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
```

Change it to

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "shoutoutDetailSegue" {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? shoutoutDetailViewController {
        // Here `Model` should be your class or struct
        destination.shoutoutSelected = sender as! Model
    }
}
```

OR move your logic here from `didSelectRowAt`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "shoutoutDetailSegue" {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? shoutoutDetailViewController {
        if isFiltering == true {
            object = filteredShoutout[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            object = shoutout[indexPath.row]
        }
        destination.shoutoutSelected = object
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Razi, thanks for the tip. I did something similar to your second method and it worked: if filtering is true, destination.shoutoutselected = filteredShoutout[tableview....];  if filtering is false, destination.shoutoutselected = shoutout[tableview....]

Comment: @estelyk accept the answer if this indeed answers the above question and solved your problem.